# Apache2 redirect Alias to port

Tags: linux, mod-rewrite, apache2, raspberry-pi, mod-proxy

i know this can be done with mod_rewrite or mod_proxy, if i'm correct..
but the problem is that i've tried so many times without success.

My problem is that i have a server mapped on 192.168.1.110, with two open ports (80 apache2 and 8080 tomcat)

I want to install something like shellinabox that runs on port 4200, and redirect it to a apache2 alias like : http://mywebsite.com/shellinabox
without having to open port 4200 on my router.

How to do that?
Any working solution?

Thanks

Comment: what is shellinabox actual URL? is it based on tomcat?

Comment: https://scottlinux.com/2010/12/15/shellinabox-with-apache-authentication-over-https-443/